# Edit ShareLaTeX document using Emacs

Tags: latex

I was searching whether is is possible to edit a document from ShareLaTeX using Emacs in real time. Up to now I haven't find anything to do the job. So my question is if there is a good and reliable way to do that.

Comment: Has you looked at the code? It is **nothing** there. I'm afraid it can't do anything.

Comment: @cutejumper Wow you are right! I will edit the question and leave that "plug-in" outside. Thank you. :)

Comment: There is a mention on the website about syncing to both dropbox and github, so that is probably the easiest way to go -- I don't know how other people editing at the same time would affect that though (probably problematic if simultaneous edits are occurring).  I see no obvious mention of a formal API for the end user to build custom tools for interaction with the website.